# Is Apache running in Docker multi-process on Os?

Tags: docker, apache

I have set up a container running Apache in Docker.
I understand that Apache generally runs in a multi-process manner. I am wondering, is Apache in Docker running multi-processes for the CPU of the OS running Docker?

We can see that when we run Docker on Ubuntu it is running as a single process with the ps aux command. But is it possible to be multi-process in it? This is also a question about the behaviour of Docker itself.

Comment: This depends entirely on how you've configured it. There's absolutely no reason why a container can't have multiple processes in it.

Comment: @tadman Is it correct to assume that multiprocesses in Docker are equivalent to multiprocesses on Os?

Comment: Docker is just a way of "containing" things. If you're running Docker directly on your system it's not in a virtual machine, and it's not different OS. Think of it like `chroot` but way stronger.